# Multivariate normal log-likelihood computation in R

Tags: r, likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm trying to use the `dmvnorm` function from the `mvtnorm` package to compute the log-likelihood of a random normal vector. However, when I check the output of `dmvnorm` against my computation of the log-likelihood function the `dmvnorm` output is always almost exactly my result multiplied by 1.7. What's going on? Am I computing the likelihood wrong? Am I using the `dmvnrom` function wrong? Here's my code

```
x <- rmvnorm(1, sigma = C1)
loglik <- dmvnorm(x, sigma = C1, log = T) 
y <- t(x)
deter2pi <- function(mat){
    determinant(2*pi*mat)[[1]][1]
}
ll <- (-0.5*t(y)%*%solve(C1,y)-0.5*log(deter2pi(C1)))[1]
loglik/ll # = 1.7
```

And my covariance matrix

```
> round(C1,3)
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 1.000 0.743 0.545 0.421 0.309 0.215 0.159 0.120 0.084 0.059
 [2,] 0.743 1.000 0.733 0.564 0.413 0.289 0.213 0.161 0.113 0.079
 [3,] 0.545 0.733 1.000 0.766 0.561 0.393 0.290 0.220 0.154 0.108
 [4,] 0.421 0.564 0.766 1.000 0.732 0.511 0.377 0.286 0.200 0.141
 [5,] 0.309 0.413 0.561 0.732 1.000 0.695 0.515 0.390 0.273 0.192
 [6,] 0.215 0.289 0.393 0.511 0.695 1.000 0.736 0.559 0.391 0.275
 [7,] 0.159 0.213 0.290 0.377 0.515 0.736 1.000 0.758 0.531 0.372
 [8,] 0.120 0.161 0.220 0.286 0.390 0.559 0.758 1.000 0.700 0.491
 [9,] 0.084 0.113 0.154 0.200 0.273 0.391 0.531 0.700 1.000 0.699
[10,] 0.059 0.079 0.108 0.141 0.192 0.275 0.372 0.491 0.699 1.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, determinant returns the log of the determinant.

```
   x <- rmvnorm(1, sigma = C1)
    loglik <- dmvnorm(x, sigma = C1, log = T) 
    y <- t(x)
    deter2pi <- function(mat){
        determinant(2*pi*mat,log=FALSE)[[1]][1]
    }
    ll <- (-0.5*t(y)%*%solve(C1,y)-0.5*log(deter2pi(C1)))[1]
    loglik/ll
```

does return the value 1 for the ratio.